# create-react-app + react-bootstrap: how to add a CDN link to bootstrap css?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx, cdn

I am trying to follow the react-bootstrap.github.io within an application created using create-react-app.

How do I add the CDN links to the bootstrap & bootstrap theme?  I was able to npm install --save version 3.3.7 and reference it via imports in my index.js, but I was wondering if there was a way I could just use the CDN link below:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

Thanks, Dennis

Comment: In public/index.html as you would anywhere else...

Comment: Deleting my answer.  You were here first.

Comment: Thanks!  public/index.html it is! Thanks for your help!